# How to terminate a process in c++?

Tags: c++, windows, process

I'm trying to kill an external c++ process with the following code:

```
    char tKill[40];
    int pid = 3200; //here goes the proces_id

    int n =sprintf(tKill, "taskkill /F /PID %d ", pid);
    tKill[n-1] = '\0';
    char *com = tKill;
    system(com);
```

But when i start it, it doesn't kill the process. Im running it on windows. I have already tried TerminateProcess() function, but it didn't work. 
But when i try:
system("taskkill /F /PID 3200");
 It works.

What might be the reason?

Comment: You say `TerminateProcess()` doesn't work. Why doesn't it work? What's the [error code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686714(v=vs.85).aspx) you get? Generally you want to use the proper way, rather than working around it with a hack like the above.

Comment: Before calling `TerminateProcess()`, did you call `OpenProcess()` to open the process ID with `PROCESS_TERMINATE` rights, and did it actually succeed and return a value `HANDLE`?

Comment: FYI, `sprintf()` null-terminates the buffer for you, you do not have to do it manually. And you can pass `tKill` directly to `system()`, you don't need `com`.

Comment: i tried this:  HANDLE oProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, 6036);
  if (oProcess == 0)
  {
   printf("Error");
  }
  TerminateProcess(oProcess, 0);

Comment: @user2453894, No need to require all access, and you haven't told us the error code.

Comment: the error i got is "Not enough memory to complete this operation"